# Delay in placing order and therefore the production stopped. Need to save my job

Tags: professionalism, project-management

how to save your job when you have forgotten to place an order and the production of plant stopped for more than 2 hrs? Please I need to save my job. Kindly guide me

Comment: Sir this is my first job and its only a month back I hv joined in.

Comment: Terrible mistake to make if you have only been there a month, is it a junior position?

Comment: Specifying which country you are in, the type of contract and whether you're within a trial period would probably help...

Answer (score 4):

It is not certain you can save your job, but there are things you can do that increase the probability.

I hope that as soon as you knew about the mistake you did everything you could to mitigate its effects. That includes bringing it to the attention of anyone who could, for example, choose to spend money to expedite the order.

The next thing to do is to come up with a plan for preventing similar mistakes in the future. That may mean a prominent order schedule in your work area, or use of an electronic calendar. It has to be some system that makes it somewhere between impossible and very, very unlikely that there will be a repetition. Ideally, it should be accessible to others so that an order is unlikely to be forgotten even if you are off sick.

Beyond that, all you can do is apologize and point out the steps you have taken to avoid repeats.

As Kilisi pointed out in a comment, there may already be a procedure in place that you should have followed to prevent this sort of mistake. If so, find out what it is, and set up a plan for following it.

Comment: On the plus side, a company that entrusts someone a month into their first job with something so critical is probably accustomed to unexpected problems by now.

Comment: @Carson63000 I hope that the fact that happened so early in the job will weigh in the OP's favor, but I don't recommend the OP presenting that as an excuse. The OP should focus on the things the OP can change.

Comment: Yep firing someone for making a mistake so early in their employment is counter-productive: you're just going to have to replace them with another new hire who is equally likely to make the same mistake. I agree that it's great advice to focus on how to avoid similar mistakes, and to make it clear to the boss that the OP is indeed doing that, unprompted, because they don't want to ever make the same mistake again.

Comment: I would think it's likely that there were already procedures in place to stop this happening, but the OP either forgot them or didn't understand them correctly, rather than having to make up new ones to prevent a re-occurence. Apart from that this is a good answer, so +1 from me.

Comment: @Kilisi Good point.